# Powertop systemd service Status - Not sure if it is working

Tags: systemd, services, battery, powertop

I enabled the powertop service. It always shows the following:

```
$ sudo systemctl status powertop -l
○ powertop.service - Extend the battery life of laptop
     Loaded: loaded (/lib/systemd/system/powertop.service; enabled; vendor preset: enabled)
     Active: inactive (dead) since Wed 2022-11-02 17:39:20 CET; 2min 4s ago
    Process: 192272 ExecStart=/usr/sbin/powertop --auto-tune (code=exited, status=0/SUCCESS)
   Main PID: 192272 (code=exited, status=0/SUCCESS)
        CPU: 3.266s

Nov 02 17:39:15 lamy powertop[192272]: glob returned GLOB_ABORTED
Nov 02 17:39:18 lamy powertop[192272]: Leaving PowerTOP
Nov 02 17:39:20 lamy powertop[192272]: Cannot load from file /var/cache/powertop/saved_parameters.powertop
Nov 02 17:39:20 lamy powertop[192272]: File will be loaded after taking minimum number of measurement(s) with battery only
Nov 02 17:39:20 lamy powertop[192272]: Cannot load from file /var/cache/powertop/saved_parameters.powertop
Nov 02 17:39:20 lamy powertop[192272]: File will be loaded after taking minimum number of measurement(s) with battery only
Nov 02 17:39:20 lamy powertop[192272]: To show power estimates do 113 measurement(s) connected to battery only
Nov 02 17:39:20 lamy systemd[1]: powertop.service: Deactivated successfully.
Nov 02 17:39:20 lamy systemd[1]: Finished Extend the battery life of laptop.
Nov 02 17:39:20 lamy systemd[1]: powertop.service: Consumed 3.266s CPU time.
```

How can I find out if its working fine?

Comment: Try: `sudo journalctl -x -u powertop.service`. You could get a more detailed logs about your service.

Comment: This service has exited with exit code 0.   Exit code 0 is usually good unless it doesn't give accurate status (program-specific), or it is intended to be a long-running service.  In your case, it looks bad because the journal messages complain about being unable to open a file.

Comment: @Stewart `/var/cache/powertop/saved_parameters.powertop` file does not exists. I checked it. Any suggestions?